# I can get 1 or 3 'None' values, but not 2

Tags: python, zip, python-itertools

Here is what I have:

```
item_dictionary = {'10350': 'Third-Age Full', '560':'Death Rune'}

filler = []
for i in range(0,365):
    filler.append(None)

filler1=[]
for i in range(0, 2):
    filler1.append(None)

filler2=[]
for i in range(0, 1):
    filler2.append(None)

names = item_dictionary.values()
names_filled = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(names, filler1 * len(names))))
#Returns ['Death Rune', None, 'Third-Age Full', None]
```

And

```
names = item_dictionary.values()
names1 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(names, filler2 * len(names))))
names_filled = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(names1, filler1 * len(names))))
#Returns ['Death Rune', None, None, None, 'Third-Age Full', None, None, None]
```

I'm trying to get `['Death Rune', None, None, 'Third-Age Full', None, None]` but I can't seem to, can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
In [171]: item_dictionary = {'10350': 'Third-Age Full', '560':'Death Rune'}

In [172]: names = item_dictionary.values()

In [173]: [n for name in names for n in [name, None, None]]
Out[173]: ['Death Rune', None, None, 'Third-Age Full', None, None]
```

or if you want to easily change the number of `None`s to some other value,

```
In [174]: [n for name in names for n in [name] + [None]*2]
Out[174]: ['Death Rune', None, None, 'Third-Age Full', None, None]
```

Comment: Thank you, I suppose I was too narrow-minded in thinking this through.

Comment: I thought it should be possible with a list comprehension, but I couldn't get the ordering right, and had to fall back on itertools in the end myself. Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can create those filler things easier:

```
filler = [None] * 365
filler1 = [None] * 2
filler2 = [None]
```

And to actually answer your problem, you can zip more than two iterables, so you could just zip a third filler to it:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(names, [None] * len(names), [None] * len(names))))
['Third-Age Full', None, None, 'Death Rune', None, None]
```

And then you could also make use of `itertools.zip_longest` which won’t require you to expand those filler iterables at all, but just expand them automatically (`zip_longest` will use `None` as its fillvalue per default):

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(names, [], [])))
['Third-Age Full', None, None, 'Death Rune', None, None]
```

Or, as unutbu suggested, use list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Won't this do what you want?

```
names_filled = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[n,None,None] for n in names])
```